# Assign value to HTML textbox from JSP

Tags: html, sql, jsp, ms-access

Hello I am creating a web page to add some information about given product.I need to enter id,name,description and image as information.I need the id to be auto generated.I am using jsp and database as access.I am fetching the count(*)+1 value from database and assigning to my html text box but its showing as null.can i get some help?

Code:

```
<body>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%! String no; %>
<%
try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:pd");
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = ("select count(*)+1 from products");
st.executeUpdate(sql);
while (rs.next()) { 
no=rs.getString("count(*)+1");
}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}
%> 
<Form name='Form1' action="productcode.jsp" method="post">
<table width="1024" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="126">Add Product: </td>
    <td width="277">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="583">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Product Id:</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="text" name="id" value="<%= no%>"/>
    </label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
.... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a query to get the data like this

```
          String sql = ("select count(*)+1 from products");
          st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The statement

```
            executeUpdate()
```

only  used to do the operations like INSERT,UPDATE

try

```
             rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

instead of  executeUpdate()

Comment: thanks the code i working but i want the max value i.e pid which is string and +1 to it means it will act as id for the next product any sugesstions plz?

Comment: select * from tablename order by id desc limit 1

Answer (score 2):

```
  {..}.executeQuery("Select max(id) from tablename");
```

This will return the `ID` with the largest number. Its more efficient than `select * from tablename order by id desc limit 1`.

However, it looks like your trying to guess/generate an `ID` of an object which doesn't yet exist in the database. This isn't the best way, and you may find that the `ID` your generating may be different to that generated by your DB. It could also cause duplication errors if two people are trying to create two new objects at the same time.

I would suggest that you don't provide a product id until the "create product" button has been pressed. Use `@@IDENTITY;` in your SQL command to set the new `ID` to your product safely.

Comment: my id field is in var char format so when i select id it default returns max id . and +1 for good suggestion.

Comment: can I ask why you are using varchar as an identity? It sounds unusual to save the number id as a string, perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: great, did this help solve your issue? if so, would you make it as an answer?