# Show auto-increment ID from database into a html text-field with JSP

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, auto-increment

This question was asked earlier in 2016 but the guy that asked didn't get the answer. So does anyone know how to get this ID which is already AI but I need it shown automatically in a html form.
So I am inserting a new user which still doesn't have ID assigned .

```
       <h3>Kreirati korisnika</h3>
    <form action="kreiraj_korisnika.jsp">
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="id_clan" >ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_clan" name="id_clan">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get the next possible Id.
Check this for the instructions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Then you can work with the data:

The textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_clan" name="id_clan" value="<%= yourId%>"/>
```

JSP code:

```
<%! String yourId; %>
<%
  //do some code to receive your data
  yourId="YOUR_ID";
%>
```

See here for more info:
[Assign value to HTML textbox from JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436040/assign-value-to-html-textbox-from-jsp)

or

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pass-the-text-entered-into-an-HTML-text-box-to-a-Java-method-if-I-am-using-JSP

Comment: But that is the problem, I don't know how to receive my data if it hasn't been inserted into database yet ?

Comment: sso you mean you have the data, but it is not already inserted in the database?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014140/how-to-get-last-inserted-id-into-jdbc-in-jsp
and this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405393/finding-the-next-available-id-in-mysql

Comment: No, I am adding a new user to the database through html and I want my Id to generates automatically in the textfield

Comment: @MilicaMiletic you have to get the last inserted record and then just add 1+ to the received id: see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: I add it to my answer and you can mark it as solution if it helped. Thx